# Is there any alternative ways other than loop to update the dictionary from any sequence data (Python)?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, optimization

I have a code to update a dictionary like this :

```
c = { }
for i in ID :
    d = {i : V[i]}
    c.update(d)
```

Both ID and V are sequence data with a complex and huge items, where ID is a list and V is a dictionary.

Is there any ways in python to do that logic without using loop processes like "for"?

The use of loop processes take a lot of iteration impacted on run time.

Comment: Simply use `c[i] = V[i]` inside the loop.

Comment: I don't understand: it sounds like you're asking, "Is there any way to update every item in a sequence without visiting every item in the sequence?" It should be obvious the answer is no. What am I missing?

Comment: No way to do it without some kind of loop, but your code would appear to be identical to `c = { i: V[i] for i in ID }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the short way of your code is:

```
c.update({i:V[i] for i in ID})
```

also you could use `map`, but it will iterate over

```
c.update(dict(map(lambda i:(i,V[i]),ID)))
```

Its all O(n) and you could just move it into `C` part rather than Python by using above notations!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's faster 5 second

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't avoid a loop but you can try these alternatives:

```
c = { }
for i in ID :
    c[i] = V[i]
```

or

```
c = dict([(i, V[i]) for i in ID])
```

or

```
c = {i: V[i] for i in ID}
```

Comment: "The use of loop processes take a lot of iteration impacted on run time." While I would prefer at least one of these to OP's sample code, I don't think this answers the question. All of these are basically O(n), which I think is that OP wants to avoid (impossible).

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, true, but using a dictionary comprehension may be faster than building the dictionary one entry at a time.

Comment: Yes, certainly the provided sample can be optimized.

Comment: You can also `c = dict((i, V[i]) for i in ID)`,  you don't need to build the list first